# Sudoku Solver in C printing

Tags: c, printing, sudoku

Okay so I have all this code for a sudoku solver (it's not done, I still need my find next function and legal move function) but I could use some help with printing. The code asks for the user to upload a file to read, and then prints out the puzzle. This means sudoku can be 3x3 or 4x4, all the way  up to 25x25. What I need help with, is in my print_puzzle function, how do I make sure that it prints out in blocks? Like if it was 3x3, there would be 9 3x3 boxes for the puzzle, etc. Hopefully that makes sense, anyways here's the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    bool prompt_for_file (void);
    bool load_puzzle(char filename[]);
    void print_puzzle (void);
    bool solve_puzzle(void);
    bool find_next( int *row, int *col, int dir);
    bool legal_move(int num; int row; int col);

    #define MAX_SIZE 25
    #define FORWARD 1
    #define BACKWARD 0

    int puzzle[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
    int puzzle_size;
    int block_size;


    int main(void)
    {
       if (!prompt_for_file())
       {return -1;}

       print_puzzle();

       if (solve_puzzle())
       {print_puzzle();}
       else
       {return -1;}

       return 0;
    }


    bool solve_puzzle(void)
    {
       int dir;
       int R;
       int C;
       int n;
       int previous_n;
       dir = FORWARD;
       while(find_next(&R, &C, dir))
       {
       dir= BACKWARD;
       previous_n=abs(puzzle[R][C]);
       puzzle[R][C]= 0;
       for (n=previous_n+1; n<=puzzle_size; n++)
        {
         if (legal_move(n, R, C))
         {
          puzzle[R][C] = -n;
          dir = FORWARD;
          break;
         }
        }
       }
       if (dir== FORWARD)
       {return true;}
       else
       {return false;}
    }


    void print_puzzle (void)
    {
    int r;
    int c;
    printf("\n");
    for (r=0;r<puzzle_size;r++)
       {
          for (c=0;c<puzzle_size;c++)
          {
             printf("%3d", abs(puzzle[r][c]));
    //put something in to define blocks

          }
        printf("\n");
       }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*
    bool find_next( int *row, int *col, int dir)
    {
    *R=r;
    *C=c;

    }
    */

    bool prompt_for_file (void)
    {
        char filename[100];
       do
       {
          printf("Enter a file name (or ""quit""): ");
          scanf("%s",&filename[0]);

          if (  strcmp(filename,"quit")==0  )
          {
             filename[0]='\0';
             printf("quitting\n");
             return false;
          }

       } while( load_puzzle(filename)!=true );
       return true;
    }


    bool load_puzzle(char filename[])
    {
       int r;
       int c;
       int dummy;
       FILE *fileptr;

       // open the file but return if not successful
       fileptr = fopen(filename,"r");
       if ( fileptr==NULL)
       {
          printf("the file was not opened: %s\n", filename);
          return false;
       }
       else
       {
          printf("the file was opened: %s\n", filename);
       }

       // read the sizing info
       fscanf(fileptr,"%d",&puzzle_size);
       printf("the number of rows and cols: %d\n",puzzle_size);
       if (puzzle_size>MAX_SIZE)
       { 
        printf("puzzle is too big %d. Max size is %d\n", puzzle_size,MAX_SIZE);
        return false;
       }
               block_size=sqrt(puzzle_size);

               // read the data
               for (r=0;r<puzzle_size;r++)
               {
                  for (c=0;c<puzzle_size;c++)
                  {
                     if ( fscanf(fileptr,"%d",&puzzle[r][c])!=1 )
                     {
                        printf("insufficient number of elements\n");
                return false;
             }
          }
       }

       // check to see if all of the data was read
       // and that the end of the input file has been reached
       if (fscanf(fileptr,"%d",&dummy) ==1)
       {
           printf("WARNING: not all numbers from file were used.\n");
       }
       if (feof(fileptr))
       {
           printf("The end of the input file has been reached.\n");
       }

       fclose(fileptr);
       return true;
    }
```

Thank you!!:)

Comment: *how do I make sure that it prints out in blocks* - you **tell** it what to do, and it is doing it.

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer: how can I make it print in blocks? Right now it just prints as lines of numbers, and I need to make sure that the square root of the row or column has a space between them so it forms a column

Comment: Say your size is 25, put a condition - `if(c%5==0) printf(" ");` and similar for `r`. Print and extra `\n`. In general case replace 5 with `sqrt` of size.

Comment: You should be able to reduce your code to a [mcve] - no need to make everybody read your load, save and solve code if you're only asking about the printing!

Comment: Show your output and describe what you do not like about it. Your question as it is sound like you are asking how to print a " " at the rigth places. If that is the what you ask, see comment by @AjayBrahmakshatriya. Also, I second Tobys comment, that your MCVE is lacking on the M. You can demonstrate by printing random numbers.